# Difference operation on collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have the following collections:

requests:

```
    {  "requestid" : 'R1', "stocks" : [{"scripid" : "xxxxx1" }, {"scripid" : "xxxxx2" },{"scripid" : "xxxxx3" },{"scripid" : "xxxxx4" }] }
    {  "requestid" : 'R2', "stocks" : [{"scripid" : "xxxxx0" }] }
```

stocks:

```
{"scripid" : "xxxxx2" }
{"scripid" : "xxxxx3" }
{"scripid" : "..." }
```

We would like to diff request's scrips with stocks collection - and return requests(and scrips)  which are not a part of stocks collection.
So the results of mongo operation will be:

```
 {  "requestid" : 'R1', "stocks" : [{"scripid" : "xxxxx1" }, {"scripid" : "xxxxx4" }] }
 {  "requestid" : 'R2', "stocks" : [{"scripid" : "xxxxx0" }] }
```

How can this be achieved in the most efficient manner.
We are using java driver 3.7.xxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this does the trick:

```
db.requests.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "stocks",
        localField: "stocks.scriptid",
        foreignField: "scriptid",
        as: "matched_stocks"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "matched_stocks._id": 0
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        request_id: 1,
        stocks: {
            $setDifference: ["$stocks", "$matched_stocks"]
        }
    }
}])
```

Edit:

As suggested by @MrS.Sharma below, you can use `Aggregates.project(Projections.computed("stocks", Document.parse("{ $setDifference: ['$stocks', '$matched_stocks'] }")))` to use `$setDifference`.

Edit 2:

I guess this is then the actual full answer:

```
AggregateIterable<Document> documents =
    requests.aggregate(
        Arrays.asList(
            Aggregates.lookup("stocks", "stocks.scrip", "scrip", "matched_stocks"),
            Aggregates.project(Projections.exclude("matched_stocks._id")),
            Aggregates.project(
                Projections.fields(
                    Projections.include("requestid"),
                    Projections.computed(
                        "stocks",
                        Document.parse(
                            "{ $setDifference: ['$stocks', '$matched_stocks'] }"))))));
```

Comment: As mentioned above,we are using the aggregates framework of java.Do not seem to find the setdifference feature in that

Comment: I'll have a look at the Java driver, but `$setDifference` has been there since MongoDB 2.6, so I would expect it to be in the driver.

Comment: @IUnknown You can use ```Aggregates.project(Projections.computed("stocks", Document.parse("{ $setDifference: ['$stocks', '$matched_stocks'] }")))```

Comment: Thanks! You beat me to it @MrS.Sharma ;)

Comment: No luck 2 records returned but empty -  AggregateIterable<Document> documents = requests.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
    Aggregates.lookup("stocks","stocks.scrip","scrip",
             "matched_stocks"),
       Aggregates.project(Projections.include("matched_stocks")),
    Aggregates.project(
      Projections.fields(
      Projections.include("requestid"),
      Projections.computed("stocks", 
        Document.parse("{ $setDifference: ['$stocks', '$matched_stocks'] }"))))));

Comment: The second part is about excluding the `_id` field of the matched_stocks sub_document, so something like that:
`Aggregates.project(Projections.exclude("matched_stocks._id"))`

Comment: Interesting - I had actually done Aggregates.project(Projections.include("matched_stocks.scrip")) which didnt work.But excluding _id did!